# How to use both Java and Clojure in one project using Gradle plugin Clojurephant?

Tags: gradle, clojure, build.gradle

[image]

as shown in the img:

Clojure cannot find my `DumoCore` (java code)

and my DumoCore cannot call `init` from Clojure

---

I've tried editing my `build.gradle` according to https://clojurephant.dev/clojurephant/main/howto/faq.html

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.10'
    id 'dev.clojurephant.clojure' version '0.7.0'
    id 'java-library'
}

...

clojure.builds.configure {
    main {
        classpath.from = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + tasks.named(sourceSets.main.processResourcesTaskName)
        aotAll()
    }
}

tasks.named('compileJava') {
    classpath += files(sourceSets.main.clojure.classesDirectory)
}

tasks.named('compileKotlin') {
    classpath += files(sourceSets.main.clojure.classesDirectory)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, you can make a cyclic compile dep work over two compilers
in one module.  My guess is, that you would have to move the "interfacy"
parts into it's own lib module, then you can use that from clojure, and
then you can use another class in java to actually instance the clojure
class.  Or you could give up on gen-classing and dynamically load the
clojure part, but that will most likely still keep your IDE in the dark.